# Is there a way to iterate over a JSON file and write specific keys and values to a new JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to iterate over specific keys and values from a JSON file and write them to a new JSON file. I'm not getting any errors and the second JSON file is being created successfully, though the data passed onto the second JSON file is a whole object of the first JSON file.

```
def get_keys_values():
json_file = open("get_failed_archives.json")
json_data = json.load(json_file)
for archive_data in json_data["data"]:
    archive_data["latestEvent"]["objectName"]
    archive_data["latestEvent"]["time"]
    archive_data["latestEvent"]["eventType"]
    archive_data["latestEvent"]["eventStatus"]
    with open("new_json_file.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(archive_data, file)
```

Is there a way to write specific keys and values from one JSON file to another JSON file?

Comment: What error r you getting?

Comment: What does the json look like? What are the errors? Although that code is useful, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There's no error. The files is being created successfully, though I'm not able to iterate over the first JSON file as I want to. The mistake here is that I'm providing json.dump the wrong object - archive_data. I need to extract specific keys and values and instead I'm getting the whole object of the first JSON file. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `archive_data["latestEvent"]["objectName"]` just returns the object, it doesn't actually do anything; to do so you'd need to create a new dict and update it with the fields from the dict you are copying from. Also are there multiple objects in `json_data["data"]`? They will get overwritten as you're only providing a single filename. Again, context is very important and you've provided very little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated by josh, the statement `archive_data["latestEvent"]["objectName"]` functionally does nothing.

if you want to create a new JSON object, in your case this would functionally be a list of dict items (I think), the approach below would match what (I think) you want it to do.

I've added a `pprint` statement to print out what the result is.

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint


def get_keys_values():
    with open("get_failed_archives.json") as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
    new_data = []
    for archive_data in json_data["data"]:
        new_data.append({
            "objectName": archive_data["latestEvent"]["objectName"],
            "time": archive_data["latestEvent"]["time"],
            "eventType": archive_data["latestEvent"]["eventType"],
            "eventStatus": archive_data["latestEvent"]["eventStatus"]
        })
    pprint(new_data, indent=4)
    with open("new_json_file.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(new_data, file)
```